# How can I create the following Bootstrap Component?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to create the following component using Bootstrap

What I tried:

```
<style>
 .card-container {
  height:150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="jumbletron">
        <div class="card card-inverse">
          <div class="card-block">
            <h3 class="card-title text">Alerts Card</h3>

            <div class="card-container">

              <div class="card card-inverse">
                <div class="card-block">
                  <h3 class="card-title text">Alert 1</h3>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card card-inverse">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title text">Alert 2</h3>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/1/

But unfortunately couldn't figure out a way how to properly do it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean [jumbotron](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/jumbotron/) instead of `jumbletron`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you used `jumbletron` instead of `jumbotron` for the class and place one of the cards outside the container.

Updated example here - http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/5/

I also added a padding of 1rem to the card container to make it closer to your attached image.

Answer (score 1):

You have your divs a bit mixed up and not wrapping properly.

```css
.card-container {
    height:150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>My alert center</h1>

    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card card-inverse">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title text">Alerts Card</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-inverse">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title text">Alert 1</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-inverse">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title text">Alert 2</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<style>
  .jumbotron{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  } 
  .mb-10{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  } 
</style>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="card-container">
<div class="card w-50 mb-10">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card w-50 mb-10">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card w-50 mb-10">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this